# How to kick off AWS Glue Job when Crawler Completes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically kick off an AWS Glue Job when an AWS Glue Crawler completes.  I see that the Crawlers send events when they complete, but I'm struggling to parse through the documentation to figure out how to listen to that event and then launch the AWS Glue Job.

This seems like a fairly simple question, but I haven't been able to find any leads so far.  I'd appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a CloudWatch event, choose Glue Crawler state change as Event source, choose a Lambda function as Event target, and in the Lambda function you can use boto3(or other language sdk) to invoke the job to run.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [AWS Glue Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/about-triggers.html).

For anything involving more than two steps, I'd recommend using [AWS Glue Workflows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/orchestrate-using-workflows.html). They are formed by chaining Glue jobs, crawlers and triggers together into a workflow that can be visualised and monitored easily.